# STM32F411 USART2 data loss

Tags: stm32f4

I'm implementing serial communication with a device in a firmware wrote from another person.
The MCU is STM32F411VET and I've data loss in communication.
To try to understand the problem, I wrote a little firmware that manage only usart2 and with it I haven't data loss, infact in this case, the usart2 works very fine at 115200 and don't loss a single byte.
Then, I've compared the code of this test software with code of software I'm working on and they are identical.
So I checked if there is another part of code that can conflict with USART2 and I have not found anything.
I searched instruction that disable interrupts, but there is one not used in my case.
The loop time is less then one milliseconds then I think that this not a problem.
What else could I check?
I finished ideas

The init code of USART2 is:

```
__HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
__HAL_RCC_USART2_CLK_ENABLE();
GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = TX_Pin | RX_Pin;
GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH; 
GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF7_USART2;
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);{

HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(USART2_IRQn, 0, 0);
HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART2_IRQn);

huart2.Instance = USART2;
huart2.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
{
    Uart2_Ready = false;
}
```

The Rx callback is:

```
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    RxBuffer[BufferIndex++] = c;
    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(huart, (uint8_t *)&c, 1);

    if (BufferIndex == BUFFER_LENGHT)
    {
        memcpy(&Rx_Packet, RxBuffer, BUFFER_LENGHT);
        PacketReady = true;
        BufferIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

Many thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I found a function with problems.